# How to use for_each from C++ boost library?

Tags: c++, boost, compilation, foreach

I try to use [for_each](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/iteration/functions/for_each.html) from the C++ boost library. This is the code that I have.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/fusion/algorithm/iteration/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/for_each.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main() {

        vector<int> vec;
        vec.push_back(1);
        vec.push_back(2);
        vec.push_back(3);

         boost::for_each(
                vec,
                [](int val){
                        cout << val << "\n";
                }
        );

        return 0;
}
```

This is how I compile my code:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -I /opt/software/boost/1.50_ubuntu12.4lts_gcc4.7.2/include -c try_boost.cpp
g++ -o try_boost -L/opt/software/boost/1.50_ubuntu12.4lts_gcc4.7.2/lib try_boost.o -lboost
```

As a result I get:

```
error: ‘for_each’ is not a member of ‘boost’
```

Does anybody know why it does not work?

Comment: Try `boost::fusion::for_each`. I don't use it, so I don't know for sure.

Comment: @chris: That will not work either.

Comment: This `for_each` you're using doesn't work with `std::vector`. This works with tuple-like boost::vector from Fusion Library.

Comment: (Possible solution for the problem that Nawaz is mentioning: Use `std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](...){...})` instead.)

Comment: @Nawaz, Ah, it fixes the scoping problem, but just doesn't work then.

Comment: Also, why don't you use `std::for_each`?

Comment: @MichaelWild: Because it sucks that stl needs two parameters for the iterators instead of one for the range

Comment: @ViktorSehr: Really?? Then why not `#define FOR_EACH(c, f) std::for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), f)`? Or, if you like it clean, an equivalent inline function?

Comment: @MichaelWild: Because I can use boost::for_each instead, which is also documented.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using `for_each` from Boost.Fusion Library. That doesn't work with `std::vector`.

The `for_each` which you need is from Boost.Range Library.

```
#include <boost/range/algorithm/for_each.hpp> //note this difference!

boost::for_each(vec, your-lambda-expression);
```

It is defined inside `boost::range` namespace, which is brought to `boost` namespace using `using` declarative. So you can also write this:

```
boost::range::for_each(vec, your-lambda-expression);
```