# How to create my own loop version in C++?

Tags: c++

I was wondering if it possible to create custom functions like **for**, **for_each**, **while** etc.

There's nothing that I want to do that the existing loops won't do it. I am just curious to learn how they work and if I ever need to create my own.

For example if one wants to create another version of the for function that would take only parameter.

In this example, I want to to create a for that only takes one parameter, an integer.
Instead of writing

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
```

I would create a for version like this

```
for_(50)
```

and they would act the same. How would I do something like that?

I have posted this question in [another forum](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/266154/).

Comment: `for` and `while` aren't functions, they are statements that are built into and part of the language itself. You can make your own implementation of `std::for_each` or other functions that uses one of the loop statements inside.

Comment: You cannot create new language *keywords* (or modify existing ones), but you can create whatever custom *function* you like.

Comment: For inspiration, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527999/how-to-use-for-each-from-c-boost-library

Comment: Use assembly code in your custom function.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the proposals in other answers, you could create a function like the one below, but it is, at the very end, very similar to using the standard [`std::for_each`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename C, typename F>
void for_(C begin_, C end_, F&& f) { // [begin_, end_)
    for (C i =  begin_; i < end_; ++i) {
        f(i);
    }
}

template<typename C, typename F>
void for_(C count, F&& f) { // special case for [0, count)
    for_(0, count, f);
}

void mul2(int x) {
    std::cout << x*2 << " ";
}

int main() {
    for_(10, [](int i) { std::cout << i << "\n"; });
    for_(2, 10, mul2);
}
```

Comment: it sucks to know that I can't do exactly what I want but I do appreciate this piece of code, it is very useful. 
However, is there a way to make it less verbose in the line calling it??

Comment: @HBatalha AFAIK the only way you can bypass the C++ syntaxis is through a macro, but as commented in other answers, it is an ugly and not recommended solution since drawbacks will overwhelm benefits.

Answer (score 5):

An ugly and unsafe solution is to use macro:

```
#define REPEAT(i,N) for(int (i) = 0; (i) < (N); ++(i))

int main()
{
  REPEAT(i,10) std::cout << i << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not use a template function instead?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I am not sure  we can mimick the syntax `for(...) statement` with template. Have you an idea in this direction?

Comment: Honestly this can be made a lot less ugly by keeping the standard style for macros. call it REPEAT for example. That makes it obvious and is nicely expressive. Nothing to fear.

Comment: @AlexGeorg yes I do agree, I fixed my answer according to your remark

Comment: This one is the closest to what I intend, strange because it uses macros.But why all the parentheses??

Comment: @HBatalha In this peculiar case maybe some parentheses are useless, however I think it is a good habit to use them when defining macros as they avoid bugs like: `#define foo(i) std::cout << 2*i; foo(2+2);` which returns 6 without parentheses but 8 with parenthese

Comment: @PicaudVincent oh I see, but why exactly the code you gave me is usanfe in this particular case?

Comment: @HBatalha this was a piece of general advice concerning macros, see https://arne-mertz.de/2019/03/macro-evil/ In general we try to avoid them. IMHO macro must only be used when there is no other way (conditional compilation for instance: #ifdef ... etc...)

Answer (score 3):

You can't extend the C++ syntax for new loops.

You could use a macro, but this is pretty ugly, and generally best avoided. Another way to get something similar is by passing a functor as a parameter, greatly helped by the introduction of lambda expressions to C++. You can find some examples of such in the `<algorithm>` header.

For example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers = { 1, 4, 5, 7, 10 };
    int even_count = 0;
    for (auto x : numbers)
    {
        if (x % 2 == 0)
        {
            ++even_count;
        }
    }
    auto even_count2 = std::count_if(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), [](int x) { return x % 2 == 0; });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a lambda function and pass in a function object as a parameter to be performed for every iteration of the loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    auto for_ = [](int start, int size, std::function<void (int i)> fn)
    {
        int end = start + size;

        for (int i = start; i < end; ++i)
        {
            fn(i);
        }
    };

    for_(0, 10, [](int i) { std::cout << i << std::endl; });
    for_(0, 10, [](int i) { std::cout << i*2 << std::endl; });
}
```

It seems like you are reinventing the wheel here a bit. You could just use `std::for_each`.

However, you could have custom lambda functions that do different things and just implement the operation within the lambda itself without taking in a function object for the operation.